# IndentationError: unexpected indent while creating python3 virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Previously my `virtualenv` command was fully working for python3. But now when I try to create a virtual environment:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 .
```

It gives me following error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3
Already using interpreter /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/home/user/anaconda3'
New python executable in /home/user/Documents/cynical/sitemap/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/user/Documents/cynical/sitemap/bin/python (you must use /home/user/Documents/cynical/sitemap/bin/python3)
Command /home/user/Documents.../sitemap/bin/python3 -m pip config list had error code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2635, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 870, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1173, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1019, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1046, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    config = _pip_config(py_executable, python_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1128, in _pip_config
    config[key] = ast.literal_eval(value)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I have tried updating the pip3, python3 and virtualenv also.

```
$ apt install python3
$ apt install python3-pip
$ apt install virtualenv
```

Comment: The problem is in anaconda python. Reinstall it with anaconda.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. Does my virtualenv depends on anaconda? @phd

Comment: Perhaps you added anaconda to your `$PATH` so now `python` is anaconda python.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! I did:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Hope this works for you as well!